# Nested Query in SOQL

Tags: soql, error

I would return the Name of the User in PermissionSetAssignement for a specific PermissionSet. Here is my code:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM User 
WHERE Id in (SELECT AssigneeId 
             FROM PermissionSetAssignment
             WHERE PermissionSetId in (SELECT Id 
                                       FROM PermissionSet 
                                       WHERE Name like 'Project_Pulse_PM_Mind'
                                       )
             )
```

This is the error that it returns:

```
    MALFORMED_QUERY:
PermissionSetId in (SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name like 'Project_Pulse_PM_Mind'))
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:124
Nesting of semi join sub-selects is not supported
```

Someone know I could resolve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't nest 2 or more sub-selects, indeed. But you can reference fields from parent objects in your query. So change it to:

```
SELECT Name from User where Id in (SELECT AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Name like 'Project_Pulse_PM_Mind')
```

Also if you are filtering for an exact permission set name, consider changing the 'like' to an equals ('=') as that will normally give better query performance.

```
SELECT Name from User where Id in (SELECT AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Name = 'Project_Pulse_PM_Mind')
```